# Discord Error Loading JSON File: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: discord, python-3.7

When i execute my code i receive next problem.Someone have a idea what i maked wrong in this code?

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Adryan\Desktop\bot\cogs\events.py", line 51, in on_member_join
    users = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\Adryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Adryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Adryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Adryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

```py
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
       with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
           users = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Do you have a `users.json` file?  Is it empty?

Comment: Yep i have users.json and is empty

Comment: Empty files are not valid json. An empty mapping is `{}` and an empty array is `[]`